# Modify Apache directory listings?

Tags: indexes, apache-1.3

When I use

```
Options +indexes
```

...in an .htaccess file, Apache (1.3) displays a formatted list of files in that directory.  Yay!  However, the actual layout of that formatting kind of sucks; the filenames are only about 20 characters wide, and get truncated with ".." on the end.  Is there any way to change how Apache formats the width of the various text here?  (Aside from, you know, editing the source code.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with mod_autoindex.  You're looking for 'FancyIndexing' and 'IndexingOptions'.

[mod_autoindex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_autoindex.html#indexoptions)